# non-linear optimization in R using alabama package

Tags: r, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to solve a non-linear optimization problem in R using package alabama.
After defining the objective function like this:

```
fn <- function(x)
{
  -(database4[1,1] * x[1] + database4[1,2] * x[1] * x[1] +
      database4[2,1] * x[2] + database4[2,2] * x[2] * x[2]+database4[3,1] * x[3] + database4[3,2] * x[3]* x[3]
  database4[4,1] * x[4] + database4[4,2] * x[4] * x[4])
}
```

I've defined the inequality like this :

```
hin <- function(x) {
  h <- rep(NA, 1)  
  h[0] <- (database4[1,3]+database4[2,3] +database4[3,3] +database4[4,3]+ 1) - 
  (x[1] + x[2] +   x[3] + x[4])
  h[1] <- x[1] - database4[1,5]
  h[2] <- database4[1,6] - x[1]
  h[3] <- x[2] - database4[2,5]
  h[4] <- database4[2,6] - x[2]
  h[5] <  x[3] - database4[3,5]
  h[6] <- database4[3,6] - x[3]
  h[4] <- x[4] - database4[4,5]
  h[6] <- database4[4,6] - x[4]
  h
 }
```

Then the objective function is called with hin function like this:

```
constrOptim.nl(par=c(database4[1,3], database4[2,3], database4[3,3], database4[4,3]), fn=fn,      heq=NULL, hin= hin, control.outer = list(itmax= 3000))
```

The values used are to be automated, so cell references are used. 
And this is the given database4

The error that i get is...

```
"Error in if (any(hin(theta, ...) <= 0)) stop("initial value not feasible") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed"

traceback() - "2: adpbar(par, fn, gr, hin = hin, hin.jac = hin.jac, control.outer = outer.ctrl, 
       control.optim = optim.ctrl, ...)
1: constrOptim.nl(par = c(database4[1, 3], database4[2, 3], database4[3, 
       3], database4[4, 3]), fn = fn, heq = NULL, hin = hin, control.outer = list(itmax = 3000))"
```

Please help!

Comment: It means for some value of `hin`'s inputs you're getting either a `NULL` or `NA`, which causes `any` to return same, causing `if` to fail.

Comment: How do i remove this? Do i employ a default if condition to convert all NAs into 0s? That didn't work.

Comment: Quite possibly `any(hin(theta,...)<=0,na.rm=TRUE)` is all you need.  Check `?any` for more info.

Comment: This didn't work Carl

Comment: The first two rows of the database4 has calculated values. I must mention the last two rows that caters for the x[3] and x[4] and inequalities h[5], h[6], h[7], h[8] contain all values as zero.
What values should i keep in these 2 rows, so i use my objective function and inequality constraints(containing all 4 x variables) and still manages to converge the function subject to constraints.

Comment: That's a far bigger question, and probably more suited to stats.stackexchange.